# mySQLdump version mismatch - but I have the newest of both

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, mismatch, mariadb-10.3

I  have read all the other similar questions regarding this issue, and the most recent one is 7 years old so none of the version or the links provided have been helpful to me.

I am using XAMPP (Control Panel v3.3.0, compiled Apr 6th, 2021) which apparently uses MariaDB  version 10.4.19-MariaDB - mariadb.org binary distribution.

Until recently, MySQL Workbench worked well with my local version of MariaDB (and the version that is installed on the web (which is apparently 10.3.36-MariaDB).  But now I'm trying to export and I get the following message:
*mysqldump.exe is version 8.0.30 but the MySQL Server to be dumped has version 10.3.36.
It is recommended you upgrade or downgrade your local MySQL client programs, including mysqldump to a version equal to or newer than that of the target server.*

I cannot downgrade my MariaDB version to 8, and MySQL Workbench is the newest one available (I just downloaded and installed the newest one hoping it would solve the problem).  But I still get the same problem.  When I try to export I get this error message:

*Couldn't execute 'SELECT COLUMN_NAME, JSON_EXTRACT(HISTOGRAM, '$."number-of-buckets-specified"')                FROM information_schema.COLUMN_STATISTICS WHERE SCHEMA_NAME = 'MySchemaName' AND TABLE_NAME = 'FirstTableInList';': Unknown table 'COLUMN_STATISTICS' in information_schema (1109)
Operation failed with exitcode 2*

Would someone be willing to try and help me out?  What shall I try next?
I am not very technical, so please don't assume I have any background knowledge in any of these technologies.  I would need very specific instructions.

Thank you in advance

CJ

Comment: Do you have an instance of MySQL installed as well as XAMPP

Comment: I think you do, probably installed when you installed Workbench, there is a install that does both, for obvious reasons and if you didnt notice you will have installed MySQL.

Comment: Go to the menu File -> Preferences and in the dialog select Administration. In that dialog there are 3 boxes you can configure to point to the `mysql` and `mysqldump` tools. Point your to the XAMPP folders version of MySQL not the actual MySQL folders (sorry if thats a bit confusing)

Comment: mysql 8 and mariadb are very different, maybe workbench 6.3 would yield better rsults

Comment: The root cause of the problem is a common misunderstanding that mariadb and mysql are the same. They are not. Mariadb forked from mysql over 13 years ago and the list of incompatible differences are pages long by now. Mysql workbench is a GUI tool created by mysql **for** mysql, not for mariadb. You can use it with mariadb at your own risk. If it does not work with mariadb then there is nothing we can do about it. You need to install mariadb's version of mysqldump and use it from the command line to back your database up.

Comment: I agree with Shadow's comment. MariaDB 10 is not 2 higher than MySQL 8. They are totally different products with distinct versioning sequences. As you have seen, clients designed to work with current MySQL do not work with MariaDB, and over time they are going to continue growing further apart with respect to compatibility. You should drop the idea that they are compatible products.

Comment: First, a big thank you to everyone who answered and tried to help.  I did understand that MariaDB and MySQL were not the same.  The issue was not MySQL or MariaDB, but rather the sqldump version USED by MySQL Workbench.  Today my PHPTutor solved the problem.  (RiggsFolly above got closest to the actual answer, but I didn't know enough to know which folder to go to in order to identify which mysqldump.exe file I needed to enter.)  So this has been solved by setting the preferences under Administration to D:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqldump.exe.  Again - thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0):

First, a big thank you to everyone who answered and tried to help. I did understand that MariaDB and MySQL were not the same. The issue was not MySQL or MariaDB, but rather the sqldump version USED by MySQL Workbench. Today my PHPTutor solved the problem. (RiggsFolly above got closest to the actual answer, but I didn't know enough to know which folder to go to in order to identify which mysqldump.exe file I needed to enter.) So this has been solved by setting the preferences under Administration to D:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqldump.exe. Again - thanks everyone!